# Python - unable to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server, database-connection

Using Python, I need to perform some data manipulations between two SQL Server databases, so therefore, I need to establish a connection to them. I specify the connection parameters as follows:

```
gconf = json.loads(read_file('ei_config/global.json'))
gconf['sconn'] = {
        "server": "DESKTOP-S7CDEML\MSSQLSERVER1",
        "database": "DB1",
        "user": "sa",
        "password": "password"
    }
gconf['tconn'] = {
        "server": "DESKTOP-S7CDEML\MSSQLSERVER1",
        "database": "DB2",
        "user": "sa",
        "password": "password"
    }
```

Just as seen in my SSMS when I connect to the Server:

[image]

However, when I run my Python file, I get this connection error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx", line 646, in pymssql._pymssql.connect
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 2120, in pymssql._mssql.connect
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 710, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1829, in pymssql._mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
  File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1846, in pymssql._mssql.raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (DESKTOP-S7CDEML)\nDB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable 
to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (DESKTOP-S7CDEML)\n')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telm.py", line 269, in <module>
    process_main(obj)
  File "telm.py", line 256, in process_main
    .initialize_Object_Log(1) \
  File "telm.py", line 189, in initialize_Object_Log
    with self.target_connection() as sql_conn:
  File "telm.py", line 54, in target_connection
    autocommit=True)
  File "src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx", line 652, in pymssql._pymssql.connect
pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (DESKTOP-S7CDEML)\nDB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (DESKTOP-S7CDEML)\n')
```

Can you give me a clue what is wrong here and why I can't connect to the database?

Comment: FYI [The Pymssql Project is Being Discontinued](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668). You might want to look at a different library before you go too far down the rabbit hole.

Comment: maybe try `pyodbc` instead in view of above comment...